# Inheritance in C# and call to base.X() using overriden function Y()

Tags: c#, inheritance

I need to know something about inheritence in C#. I have a class shown below:

```
Class BaseClass
{
    public void X()
    {
        //Some code here
        Y();
    }

    public void Y()
    {
        //Some code here
    }
}
```

Now I want to create another class(ChildClass) which derived from BaseClass. The problem is that somehow I want to override Y() function in ChildClass, and when the base.X() function is called, I want X() function to use overridden Y() function in ChildClass.

Someone suggested me to use 'delegate' keyword for Y function when overriding. But, I am not quite sure that this is gonna work.

Is this possible? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
class BaseClass
{
    public void X()
    {
        // Some code here
        Y();
    }

    public virtual void Y()
    {
        // Some code here
    }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void Y()
    {
        // Some code here
    }
}
```

If at some point you want to call the `BaseClass` implementation of `Y()` in the `ChildClass` you can do this:

```
class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void Y()
    {
        // Some code here
        base.Y();
    }
}
```

Comment: please note that this not really a recommended pattern (calling a virtual method from a constructor). you can't know if the overriding function is implemented correctly. if it throws an exception, this exception will raise up to and out the constructor. throwing an exception from a constructor is bad.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ: There is no problem with constructors throwing exceptions in C#/.NET, and as a matter of fact, many framework classes do that. The actual issue about calling virtual methods within constructors is that `ChildClass.Y()` might rely on `ChildClass` being fully initialized (in particular, any private fields that `ChildClass`might have), which is not the case at the time when the `BaseClass` constructor runs.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: you're right, i'm confused with exceptions from the static class constructor. Those are nasty.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.  It is known as the [template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern.  Declare your function Y() in the base class, but mark it as abstract.  In your derived class, override this function.  Calling X() will then call the correct function.

Comment: Yes, you can use virtual or abstract.  The principle still holds.